# Assigning type at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a variable x of type T and value that is in a string.
For example I have:

```
bool x, value = "True"
int x, value = "1"
```

- **Is there a generic way to assign/parse/deserialize the value to x?**

Note that T may be referenced or primitive type!

Comment: The problem is you are not **assigning** a type, you are **converting** the value. So you would have to provide a way to convert a `string` to `anything`. Like a `Parse` method... You could use reflection for that, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [`Convert.ChangeType` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx).

This will cover all base types conversion.

Example : `var i = Convert.ChangeType("1", typeof(int));`

You can also take a look at the [`IConvertible` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) that you can use for converting your own objects from or to another type.

Finally, as codymanix said, you can rely on the OOB XmlSerialization or Binary Serialization to serialize your objects.

*[edit] you can check at compile time if the target type is convertible by wrapping the convert.ChangeType method in an utility class like this :*

```
public static class ConvertUtility
{
    public static T Convert<T>(object source) where T : IConvertible
    {
        return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(source, typeof(T));
    }              
}
```

Comment: @Steve I have tried with Convert.ChangeType. But not all native types implement IConvertible. I Tried Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));

Comment: +1 @Steve Strange I try it again and don't get the same problem.

Comment: @Steve Yes! I did also implement "where T : IConvertible" Thanks for verifying that.

Comment: @Steve: `T` does NOT have to be `IConvertible`. It's actually the `source` that has to be `IConvertible`.

Comment: @Jaroslav What do you think about IConvertible on T when having this function signature?  "private static T MyFunction<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property) where T : IConvertible"

Comment: @Amir: If it is supposed to convert some `source` object to type `T` then it is also incorrect. If you want a conversion wrapper: `public TTarget Convert<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source) where TSource : IConvertible`. This also means you can only convert types that implement `IConvertible` and quite possibly not all of them to the requested target type. Also the source type is in your case always a `string` anyway (according to your question)...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this reflection based approach some time ago. It's relatively untested though. It looks for methods called `Parse` and `TryParse`. And I didn't take care of locale (in)dependent parsing either.

```
    private static class ParseDelegateStore<T>
    {
        public static ParseDelegate<T> Parse;
        public static TryParseDelegate<T> TryParse;
    }

    private delegate T ParseDelegate<T>(string s);
    private delegate bool TryParseDelegate<T>(string s, out T result);


    public static T Parse<T>(string s)
    {
        ParseDelegate<T> parse = ParseDelegateStore<T>.Parse;
        if (parse == null)
        {
            parse = (ParseDelegate<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ParseDelegate<T>), typeof(T), "Parse", true);
            ParseDelegateStore<T>.Parse = parse;
        }
        return parse(s);
    }

    public static bool TryParse<T>(string s, out T result)
    {
        TryParseDelegate<T> tryParse = ParseDelegateStore<T>.TryParse;
        if (tryParse == null)
        {
            tryParse = (TryParseDelegate<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TryParseDelegate<T>), typeof(T), "TryParse", true);
            ParseDelegateStore<T>.TryParse = tryParse;
        }
        return tryParse(s, out result);
    }
```

Comment: Really great! Works very well!

Answer (score 0):

I know other way than doing:

```
object x;
if (theType==typeof(int))
   x = int.parse(myString);
else if (theType==typeof(bool))
  x = bool.Parse(myString);
// and so on for other types..
```

Also note that the serialized data must contain the type names because you otherwise have no chance to know if "123" is of type int or unsigned short or whatever, or if for example "Red" is an enum value, a Color object or a string.

You can use an `XmlSerializer` or `BinaryFormatter` to serialize / deserialize your objects, which does all this logic already for you.